# Imap email ids back to 0

Tags: email, imap

I built an email fetcher for a client in php which fetches emails on several imap servers (mail3.gridhost.co.uk) and every time it does so, saves the id of the latest fetched email. The next time it fetches, it fetches from this id onwards, so it doesn't have to fetch all the ids every time, which is very slow.

It worked well until today where the ids on the server were back to 0 for some reason, so my fetcher was lost.

Now my question is, is it something that imap servers do, after they reach a certain number for email ids, they go back to 0 ?

Or what could cause the ids to be reseted ?

Thanks all

Comment: FYI, the UID is never zero, and several well-known IMAP clients check that, so it would be very, very strange for that server to have such an unnoticed bug.

Comment: Are you using Message Sequence Numbers or Unique IDs?  Are you tracking the `UIDVALIDITY`?